# Best practice suggestions for iPhone application with multiple NIBs

Tags: iphone, view, switching

I am developing an application with seven NIBs.  The TabController is throwing a bunch of these into the ..More tab, which spoils the user experience.  Does anyone have advice on a better approach?

I am wondering if I should detect swipes and switch out each NIB in turn (with an eye to creating a circular experience i.e NIb 1 -> Nib 2... Nib 7 -> Nib1 etc.

Failing this, I could use a Navigation controller and switch NIBs with "Forward" & "Back" buttons.

I have tried the first idea.  I can switch NIBs after detecting a swipe, but the previous NIB won't release for some reason (and can be seen underneath the new NIB).   The second idea takes up screen space with the nav bar, and I would rather use this for the tables etc in the NIB.

Sample code and thoughts are appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

My sugestion would be to build your own custom "tabBar" as a scroll view with paging enabled. And try to use lazy loading for the NIBs.

Anyway you must find a way to recycle your resources (in a similar way that tableViews reuses the cells)